# magento api not working for customers

Tags: magento, content-management-system

i am passing following header information using "rest client" plugin of firefox to the url "**localhost/magento/api/rest/customers**",

i am pass following header information:

```
Consumer key :olnnqgwm7gm75rtbft8w1wac4kp4vwig
 Consumer secret:u9v6bdlpuopdlryc6vx0yjnslkj4vllo
 Access token : null
 Access token secret : null
```

i will give following response:

```
<magento_api>
<messages>
<error>
<data_item>
<code>401</code>
<message>
oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token
</message>
</data_item>
</error>
</messages>
</magento_api>
```

so here i want to get **Access token** and **Access token secret** how to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Access token : null
Access token secret : null
```

This is mandatory for getting the details of customer through REST Api. You have to configure the authentication  process as defined [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html), please go through the article and you will get your answer.

1. Getting an Unauthorized Request Token

> **URI**  localhost/magento/oauth/initiate
>
> **Method:**   POST
>
> **Return:  Sample Response:**     oauth_token=4cqw0r7vo0s5goyyqnjb72sqj3vxwr0h&oauth_token_secret=rig3x3j5a9z5j6d4ubjwyf9f1l21itrr&oauth_callback_confirmed=true

2.User Authorization

> **Uri**: localhost/magento/oauth/authorize
>
> **Method:**   Get
>
> **Sample Response:**  /callback?oauth_token=tz2kmxyf3lagl3o95xnox9ia15k6mpt3&oauth_verifier=cbwwh03alr5huiz5c76wi4l21zf05eb0
>
> **NOTE**:The second step of authentication. Without the user authorization in this step, it is impossible for your application to
>   obtain an Access Token.

3.Getting an Access Token

> **Uri**: localhost/magento/oauth/token
>
> **Method:**   POST
>
> **Sample Response:**  oauth_token=0lnuajnuzeei2o8xcddii5us77xnb6v0&oauth_token_secret=1c6d2hycnir5ygf39fycs6zhtaagx8pd

If you complete all the above steps you will get the Access token and secret which can be used for getting customer response

Comment: thank you chanz now i have get access_token, and secrete so i can access **"localhost/magento/api/rest/products"**  but i can't access **"localhost/magento/api/rest/customers"**

Comment: if you cannot see the customers through rest api using the access token tehn i must say your full authentication is not completed. some thing has gone wrong

Comment: I have successfully complete 2 steps. But in 3rd step I get "oauth_problem=verifier_invalid" response.

Comment: @Rathinam This project is 3+ year old. Now, I do not remember any thing about it. Sorry for it.