# OAuth token rejected error reading Magento customers from Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, rest, magento, oauth

I am new to Node.js and Magento. I have to read customers from Magento using REST API. I am getting the below error. Please review my code and guide me.

I followed the [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/permission_settings/roles_configuration.html) to configure Magento REST web service.

I am using the StrongLoop framework.

Installed > `npm oauth`

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;

var apiUrl = "http://domainname/api/rest/customers";

var oa = new OAuth(temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl, accessTokenRequestUrl, consumerKey, consumerSecret, 1.0, "http://localhost:3000/explorer", "HMAC-SHA1");

oa.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results){
    if(error) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      // store the tokens in the session

      oa.get(apiUrl, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret,
        function (error, data, response) {

          var feed = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
  });
```

Result:

> {"messages":{"error":{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=token_rejected"}]}}

Answer (score 0):

This is mandatory for getting the details of customer through REST Api. You have to configure the authentication process as defined [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html), please go through the article and you will get your answer.

I believe you dont have ouath user permission. [Follow Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847499/magento-api-not-working-for-customers/15848232#15848232)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this question is still valid but for myself I've solved this problem by cleaning up cookies after logging-in as admin user.